endomorphism and tensors
Can someone explain to me how an endomorphism can be related to a tensor $T_{1,1}$? I don't understand how a tensor, which a priori takes a linear functional and a vector and produces a scalar, can be similar to   a function such that $V \rightarrow V$.
Moreover, if the tensor was described by $T_j^i \phi^i \otimes e_j$, how will its expression be when understood as an endomorphism? Another question that worries me is, why if I calculate the components of a vector, j is the row and i the column and not the other way round?
I don't know if you need more information about what I'm worried about, if so let me know and I'll edit the post.

$T_j^i \phi^i \otimes e_j$ does not look right you have repeating covariant and contravariant indices

Such a tensor can act in several ways, because it may be applied "partially". A $(1,1)$-tensor $T$ is a good choice for an example in fact, since it can be identified to a mere matrix, as encountered in linear algebra.
Indeed, on one hand, from the matricial point of view, it behaves as the endomorphism $T : V \to V, v \mapsto T(v) = \tilde{T}v$, where $\tilde{T}$ corresponds to the matrix representation of $T$. On the other hand, that is from the tensorial point of view, it behaves as the map $T : V^* \times V \to \Bbb{R}, (u,v) \mapsto T(u,v) = u^\dagger\tilde{T}v$. To put it simply, $T(\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,)$ is a tensorial bilinear map, while $
Using the Einstein convention component-wise, we can rewrite the first map as $v \mapsto T(v) = T^\mu{}_\nu v^\nu$, which is indeed an endomorphism, while the second is given by $(u,v) \mapsto T(u,v) = T^\mu{}_\nu u_\mu v^\nu$.
In conclusion, a partial contraction with respect to the covariant index of a $(1,1)$-tensor will produce a $(1,0)$-tensor (i.e. a vector) and thus acts an endomorphim.

so what is done is a tensor contraction?

@JL14  Yes, $T$ is partially contracted when it acts as an endomorphism and fully contracted otherwise.

In your example the endomorphism maps any given vector to the effect of the functional $\phi^i$ on that vector (a scalar) multiplied by the constant $T^i_j$ and then by the vector $e_j,$ giving another vector.
$$v\mapsto (T^i_j\phi^i(v))e_j$$
This is a linear mapping of a vector space to itself because $\phi^i$ is linear.
In general a tensor will be a finite linear combination of such elementary tensors, effectively summing over $i$ and $j.$

Given any vector space $V$ over a field $K$ denote

$V^*=\mathrm{Hom}_K(V,K)$ the dual space of $V$, and
$\mathrm{End}_K(V)$ the space of $K$-linear endomorphisms of $V$.

Then there is a linear map
$$
\Phi:V\otimes_KV^*\longrightarrow\mathrm{End}_K(V)
$$
given by $\Phi(v\otimes\lambda)(w)=\lambda(w)v$. To see that $\Phi$ is actually an isomorphism when $V$ is finite dimensional is enough to see its effect on a basis $\{v_i\otimes v_j^*\}$ of $V\otimes_KV^*$ where $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{v_i^*\}_{i\in I}$ its dual basis.
